# Segmentation fault when running phpunit with hhvm

Tags: segmentation-fault, phpunit, hhvm

I am running phpunit tests within hhvm

`hhvm phpunit --configuration phpunit.xml`

When the tests are complete I get a segmentation fault and log path. When i examine the log I see the following but i'm not sure what to do to correct the issue.

Here is the log contents

```
Time: 2.82 minutes, Memory: 142.95Mb

OK (174 tests, 372 assertions)
Core dumped: Segmentation fault
Stack trace in /tmp/stacktrace.1375.log
bash-4.1# cat /tmp/stacktrace.1375.log
Host: 9be46a65b521
ProcessID: 1375
ThreadID: 7f7fe1ff4f60
ThreadPID: 1375
Name: /usr/bin/hhvm
Type: Segmentation fault
Runtime: hhvm
Version: heads/master-0-g546087bf1b0560c4a9e254fcad46a9212e42ccc2
DebuggerCount: 0

Arguments: /usr/local/bin/phpunit --configuration phpunit.xml
ThreadType: CLI

# 0  ?? at hhvm:0
# 1  __restore_rt at sigaction.c:0

PHP Stacktrace:
```

I'm running a Laravel 3 application. The tests all pass in a php 5.4 environment. 
**Phpunit Version**

`PHPUnit 4.4.0 by Sebastian Bergmann.`

**HHVM version**

```
bash-4.1# hhvm --version
HipHop VM 3.5.0-dev+2014.12.11 (rel)
Compiler: heads/master-0-g546087bf1b0560c4a9e254fcad46a9212e42ccc2
Repo schema: cf1780b3cc3857e091e924935ae6267e9794de9c
Extension API: 20140829
```

I didn't get any errors/failures when the test finished can i assume that there actually weren't any errors or is the segfault an indicator of an uncaught error or exception.

Comment: Try installing the `hhvm-nightly-dbg` package, which will provide a more useful stack trace.

Comment: Do that, and then please report it at our bug reporting tracker at https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues. StackOverflow isn't the appropriate place to report bugs.